# SFTP via java coding throws Exception and says Invalid absolute URI

Tags: java, sftp

[Followed this code](http://www.memorylack.com/2011/06/apache-commons-vfs-for-sftp.html)

I get this error, and the only change I made in the program is I have hard code the arguments as

```
String  hostName = "122.183.217.133" ; 
String username  = "root";
String password = "something";
String  localFilePath = "C://Sample.jpg";
String  remoteFilePath = "/var/www/html/intranetupload/uploads/Sample.jpg";

Jun 25, 2012 2:52:18 PM org.apache.commons.vfs2.VfsLog info
INFO: Using "C:\DOCUME~1\MEENAK~1.DCK\LOCALS~1\Temp\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Invalid absolute URI "sftp://root:***@122.183.217.133:22/var/www/html/intranetupload/uploads/Sample1.jpg".
    at sftp.sample.Main.delete(Main.java:120)
    at sftp.sample.Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Invalid absolute URI "sftp://root:***@122.183.217.133:22/var/www/html/intranetupload/uploads/Sample1.jpg".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:61)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:693)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:621)
    at sftp.sample.Main.delete(Main.java:111)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Expecting / to follow the hostname in URI "sftp://root:***@122.183.217.133:22/var/www/html/intranetupload/uploads/Sample1.jpg".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.HostFileNameParser.extractToPath(HostFileNameParser.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.URLFileNameParser.parseUri(URLFileNameParser.java:50)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileProvider.parseUri(AbstractFileProvider.java:188)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:57)
    ... 4 more
```

I don't have a domain name for the server. All I have is a ubuntu machine whose IP / username and password is known.
My work needs deletion of files in that remote Ubuntu machine.

Can you help me how to resolve the error?

Comment: Did you use exactly the same code as in the tutorial?

Comment: yes . except the argument hard coded.I used the same

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to Url encode the username and password before calling resolveFile();

So if you need to call something like:

```
manager.resolveFile("sftp://sftpuser@Location:Test!@#$%^&*()[]:;@US456564/home57556");
```

Where the username is "sftpuser@Location" and the password is "Test!@#$%^&*[]:;:

you encode just the username and password and call it like:

```
manager.resolveFile("sftp://sftpuser%40Location:Test!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*%5B%5D%3A%3B@US456564/home57556");
```

It might look a bit messy as a Sting but in the calling code there isn't much of a problem.

Answer (score 3):

by adding **jsch** in your pom file, the error will be solved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.50</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

You were probably using the following code from the [link](https://www.memorylack.com/apache-commons-vfs-for-sftp) you provided:

```java
public static String createConnectionString(String hostName,
        String username, String password, String remoteFilePath) {
    // result: "sftp://user:123456@domainname.com/resume.pdf
    return "sftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + hostName + "/" + remoteFilePath;
}
```

```java
FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(
        createConnectionString(
            "122.183.217.133", "root", "something", "/path/to/file")
        , createDefaultOptions());
```

The problem is, that you did not specify the port. Let's assume that it's `22` for you:

```java
createConnectionString("122.183.217.133:22", "root", "something", "/path/to/file")
```

**There is another issue though.**

If your username or password contain some unusual characters like `!@#$%^&*():` or others, you need to URLEncode it.
Use this method instead `createConnectionString`:

```java
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public static String createConnectionString(String hostName, String username, 
                                            String password, String remoteFilePath) {
   try {
        return "sftp://" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + ":" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") 
                         + "@" + hostName + "/" + remoteFilePath;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return "sftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + hostName + "/" + remoteFilePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful. My problem was the password. It had special characters like "! # $% ^ & * ():". So after encoding with the command URLEncoder.encode (username, "UTF-8") solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing dependencies on your pom.
It should be enough including: sshtools, jsch and commons-net.

I'm sorry I can't be sure but it's a dependencies problems.

Answer (score 0):

Only add `jsch-0.1.46.jar` in the lib file.